# cURL request to plugin repository fails 403

Tags: curl, svn, plugin-repository

I am trying to update a file in my plugin by getting the original contents from the wordpress repository via cURL

The URL is of the format https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/(plugin)/trunk/includes/example.php - visiting the URL in a browser shows the code, exactly what I am after.

However, the cURL response is

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It appears grabbing source code this way isn't allowed. `file_get_contents()` doesn't work either.

Is there a way to do this that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the WordPress forums someone answered that this only works via PHP if you set the UserAgent to a browser.

```
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';
curl_setopt( $cd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
```